# Robot Framework - perform action until condition met

Tags: pagination, robotframework

I have a scenario I am just beginning to develop automation for, but one need is to add items to the page until the table has filled and the table items are now displayed on two pages.

Once the table is filled, the count of available pages at the top right increases by one.

[image: Sample of desired page]

Thought I would reach out to see if anyone had a creative way to perform an action in Robot Framework until a condition is met - in this case I would add new fruit until the page count at top right changes to 2.

[Solution Below]

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Test case to validate paginatio
Suite Teardown  Close all browsers
Library  Selenium2Library
Resource  config.txt



*** Test Cases ***
Login
    [Documentation]  Log in and load Fruit Table page
    Login User  ${admUser}  ${admPwd}
    Open Browser  ${URL}/fruit_table.php

Validate Pagination Feature
    [Documentation]  Add Fruit table until page is added
    Generate New Page

*** Keywords ***
Generate New Page
    wait until keyword succeeds  2 minutes  2 seconds  Fill Table

Fill Table
    Create Table Entry
    Validate new page is available

Create Table Entry
    Create New Item
    Fill Out Form  ${ratfrm1}  ${rat1}
    Fill Out Form  ${ratfrm2}  ${rat2}
    Click Submit Button
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wait until keyword succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) will continuously run a keyword until it succeeds. You could write a keyword that adds an element and fails until the page count changes.

Comment: Thanks Bryan!  I plan to do just that - build a wait until keyword succeeds loop that will create the needed data until the page shows that there are two pages.  Will update this with the results once complete.

Comment: I am adding the final solution at the bottom of the original post to preserve formatting - it turned out to be way easier than I thought possible - Thanks Bryan for your guidance!